# Is it possible to rewrite JavaScript's apply function?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, overriding

I've been rewriting a lot of JavaScript's higher-order functions to get the hang of functional programming, and I'm stuck on `apply`. Is it possible to write `apply` in JavaScript? Assuming all other native functions are present, and that the ES5 spec is being used.

Comment: *"Assume all other native functions are present."* So you can use `Function#call`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Not trying to achieve anything really, just doing it for the learning experience.

Comment: Unless the target function supports currying, you're pretty much out of luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With ES5 and below, I don't think you can do it without using `eval` (see below). You can *almost* do it with a **massive** switch statment on `args.length`, but at some point, you just have to say there's a limit to the number of `cases` in that `switch`.

```
Function.prototype.newApply = function(thisArg, args) {
    switch (args.length) {
        case 0: return this.call(thisArg);
        case 1: return this.call(thisArg, args[0]);
        case 2: return this.call(thisArg, args[0], args[1]);
        // etc..
        default: throw new Error("She canna tek any more!");
    }
};
```

If you're allowing `eval`, though, you can absolutely do it — full credit to [blex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1913729/blex) for suggesting `eval`:

```
Function.prototype.newApply = function(thisArg, args) {
    var f = this,
        call = "f.call(thisArg",
        i;
    for (i = 1; i < args.length; ++i) {
        call += ", args[" + i + "]";
    }
    call += ")";
    return eval(call);
};
```

**Live Example:**

```js
Function.prototype.newApply = function(thisArg, args) {
  var f = this,
      call = "f.call(thisArg",
      i;
  for (i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) {
    call += ", args[" + i + "]";
  }
  call += ")";
  return eval(call);
};

var obj1 = {
  foo: "foo",
  bar: "bar"
};
var obj2 = {
  foo: "F",
  bar: "B"
};
function caps(o1, o2) {
  var k;
  snippet.log("this.x = " + this.x);
  for (k in o1) {
    o1[k] = o1[k].toUpperCase();
  }
  for (k in o2) {
    o2[k] = o2[k].toLowerCase();
  }
}

caps.newApply({x:42}, [obj1, obj2]);
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(obj1));
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(obj2));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Or if you want to use `Array#reduce`:

```
Function.prototype.newApply = function(thisArg, args) {
    var f = this,
        call = args.reduce(function(acc, _, index) {
            return acc + ", args[" + index + "]";
        }, "f.call(thisArg") + ")";
    return eval(call);
};
```

---

You said ES5 in your question, but just for completeness: It's really easy in ES6 thanks to the spread operator (`...`):

```
Function.prototype.newApply = function(thisArg, args) {
    return this.call(thisArg, ...args);
};
```

Comment: @blex Horrible, ugly, but interesting :)

Comment: @blex - Inventive, but I'm afraid it fails in the general case: It will only work for things that can take a round-trip through being a string. So for instance, any function that accepts an object reference won't work.

Comment: Good point @T.J.Crowder, I'm accepting this answer. Although that was quite an inventive (and simultaneously hideous) solution @blex!

Comment: @blex: But with `eval`, anything is possible -- you've inspired me, heaven forfend; I've thought of a way to do it with `eval`.

Comment: @MarcusBuffett: I've added an `eval` option which completely implements it, thanks to blex for raising the question of `eval`.

Comment: Yours is way cleaner than mine! :) _Edit: I'm not a fan of `eval` either, but it seems to be safe here._

Comment: @blex: Still, you thought of `eval`. I tend to forget that we have `eval`. (I've trained hard to forget, in fact. :-) )